# Stereoscopic Interpretation on QGIS

Tags: qgis, data, analysis, feature-extraction, stereo-imagery

I would like to know if anyone has worked with stereoscopic analysis (e.g extracting features such as drainage, forest an so on) using the following softwares: QGis, gvSIG, ILWIS or MicroImages TN Tmips.

If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

In regards to QGIS/GRASS modules to conduct stereoscopic analysis you can with these resources providing further details on general approach and some steps to their methods.

[A Survey of Stereoscopic Visualization Support in Mainstream Geographic Information Systems](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228789229_A_Survey_of_Stereoscopic_Visualization_Support_in_Mainstream_Geographic_Information_Systems)

[image]

[Stereoscopic analysis](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Stereoscopic_analysis)

> GRASS 6
>   Viewing existing data as stereo 3D
>   The d.anaglyph addon module provides an easy way to create 3D anaglyphs and stereographs. It uses the m.nviz.image module to render two viewpoints, then from those two images composes the 3D image into a single PNG file. In time it should be possible to port this functionality into NVIZ itself.

[image]

[Tutorial for GRASS module (old)](https://grass.osgeo.org/gdp/stereo-grass/index.html)